# How can I get elements from dictionary by key nested in a list?

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, dictionary

I have construction like this:

```
[{
    "meta": {
        "foo": 1, 
        "bar": "string", 
        "baz": "string2"},
    "data": [
        {"id": "1", "quant": 2, "price": 3.14},
        {"id": "2", "quant": 1, "price": 6.66}
    ]
 },
...
]
```

How can I get elements foo, bar from meta and quant, price from data?

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to SO, We are not code writing services so please post your effort next time you ask question. Refer to the documentation for more information on  [python Data Sructures.](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html)

`lists` are accessed through index , and `Dictionaries` are accessed through `keys'

Like `_list[index]` and `_dict['key']` With that basics lets move forward.

```
l= [{ "meta":{ "foo":1, "bar":"string", "baz":"string2"}, "data":[ {"id":"1", "quant":2, "price":3.14}, {"id":"2", "quant":1, "price":6.66}] } ]

>>> l[0]['meta']['foo']
1
>>> l[0]['meta']['bar']
'string'

>>> l[0]['data'][0]['price']
3.14
>>> l[0]['data'][0]['quant']
2
>>> 

>>> l[0]['data'][1]['quant']
1
>>> l[0]['data'][1]['price']
6.66
>>>
```

Comment: for dc in construction:
    for key in dc:
     print(key)